# Getting "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService" running tests with Jest

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I'm new to Nest.js, and I've been working on tests for my AuthController, and I keep getting this error, why is that?

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, UserService, JwtService).
"Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context."

```
Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If UserModel is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If UserModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserModel */ ]
  })`
```

Here's the test module config for auth.controller.spec.ts:

```
const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);

describe('AuthController', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let authService: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
  });
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AuthModule,
        UserModule,
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: async () => {
            const mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
            const uri = mongo.getUri();
            return {
              uri,
              useNewUrlParser: true,
              useUnifiedTopology: true,
            };
          },
        }),
      ],
      providers: [AuthService, UserService, JwtService, UserModel],
    }).compile();
    app = module.createNestApplication();
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
    await app.init();
    authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
  });
```

Here's the auth.module.ts file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '30m' },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, LocalAuthGuard, JwtAuthGuard],
  exports: [JwtAuthGuard],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And here's the UserModule:

```
const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name,
        schema: UserSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserModel],
  exports: [UserModel],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the `AuthService` has dependencies on `UserModel`, `UserService`, and `JwtService`, but Nest.js is unable to resolve these dependencies. This could be due to a few reasons:

- `UserModel` is not a valid provider: Make sure that `UserModel` is a valid `provider` in the current module or in a module that is imported by the current module. You can check if `UserModel` is a valid provider by checking if it is decorated with `@Injectable()`.
- `UserModel` is not part of the current module: If `UserModel` is `exported` from a separate module, make sure that the module is imported by the current module. In this case, `UserModel` is `exported` from the `UserModule`, so make sure that `UserModule` is `imported` by the `AuthModule`.
- `UserService` and `JwtService` are not provided in the current module: Make sure that `UserService` and `JwtService` are provided in the current module or in a module that is imported by the current module. In this case, `UserService` and `JwtService` are not provided in the `AuthModule`, so you need to add them to the `providers array` in the `AuthModule`.

So, the solution is,
`AuthModule` that includes `UserService` and `JwtService` in the providers array:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '30m' },
    }),
    UserModule, // make sure to import UserModule
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, LocalAuthGuard, JwtAuthGuard, UserService, JwtService],
  exports: [JwtAuthGuard],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i added those things but still getting the error, here's the github actions from the repo: https://github.com/mateomaza/todo-app-api/actions/runs/6677034984

Comment: @Mateo now what’s the new issue?

Comment: same message "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, UserService, JwtService). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context."