# Why am I getting "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, UserService, JwtService)." testing with Jest?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I'm building my first app with Nest (using Mongo and mongoose for the database), and when I try to test my AuthController, I get the following "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, UserService, JwtService). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.". I've trying everything I can find, even asked about it here already, but still.

Here's GitHub Actions from the repo to see the full issue: https://github.com/mateomaza/todo-app-api/actions/runs/6677034984/job/18146658628

**
[Getting "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService" running tests with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377531/getting-nest-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-authservice-running-tests-with?rq=2) ->

**Here's the test module config for auth.controller.spec.ts:**

```
const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);

describe('AuthController', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let authService: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
  });
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AuthModule,
        UserModule,
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: async () => {
            const mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
            const uri = mongo.getUri();
            return {
              uri,
              useNewUrlParser: true,
              useUnifiedTopology: true,
            };
          },
        }),
      ],
      providers: [AuthService, UserService, JwtService, UserModel],
    }).compile();
    app = module.createNestApplication();
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
    await app.init();
    authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
  });
```

**Here's the auth.module.ts file:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '30m' },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, LocalAuthGuard, JwtAuthGuard],
  exports: [JwtAuthGuard],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**And here's the UserModule:**

```
const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name,
        schema: UserSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserModel],
  exports: [UserModel],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: please put your code in question body